# Duda acerca de como funcionan los Sectioning Roots en html5

Tags: html5

estoy aprendiendo html5, estaba leyendo acerca de la funcionalidad de algunas etiquetas y me encontré con el termino elementos de raíz de contenido

según la pagina en donde estaba leyendo la definición de estos elementos es la siguiente(voy a traducir la cita porque esta en ingles):

> Las raíces de sección dividen las secciones de un documento en sus propios esquemas separados. Son objetos "raíz" que no tienen ancestros.

fuente: https://solidlystated.com/design/html5-sectioning-roots/

**¿a que se refiere cuando dice que no tienen ancestros?**

los elementos que se consideran sectioning roots por la especificación son: **body,blockquote,td,details,dialog,fieldset** y **figure**

**¿pero td si tiene ancestros y ese ancestro es** **tr** **no? igual para fieldset su ancestro no seria la etiqueta** **form** **?**

asi no? :

agradecería mucho si pudieran explicarme eso, es lo que menos entiendo de que no tienen ancestros pero a mi parecer si tienen y pues estoy algo confundido

```html
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>item<td>
  </tr>
</table>

<form>
  <fieldset>
     <legend>seccion<legend>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

se dice que este tipo de elementos pueden tener sus propios encabezados y secciones pero este contenido no aportara nada a los esquemas de sus ancestros

y si dice que no tiene ancestros, porque dice que no aporta nada a sus ancestros el encabezado y secciones que tengan?

**¿en que sentido no aporta nada?, no se muy bien a que se refiere con esquema,
significa que si en dado caso estos elementos tienen secciones con encabezados estas secciones y encabezados no formaran parte de la división lógica de la pagina, es decir no formarían parte de la jerarquía de secciones del resto de la pagina?**

porque figure si se relaciona a la pagina, es decir figure se relaciona a su sección en donde se pone por ejemplo una sección en la cual se esta hablando sobre Francia, luego viene un figure con una imagen y un figcaption que dice "Francia", este se relaciona con la sección, osea que se relaciona, aporta al esquema de su ancestro y este ancestro vendría siendo la sección que habla sobre Francia, no se a que se refiere cuando dice que no aporta a los esquemas de sus ancestros.

Answer (score 0):

lo que permite los section roots en html5 es armar la estructura del documento de formar jerarquizada. Los elementos HTML que indica ese articulo son elementos que no se van a anidar en la jerarquía dentro de otro si no que tiene su propia jerarquía de estructura.

Una buena explicación y con ejemplos la dan en este link https://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201103/html5_sectioning_elements_headings_and_document_outlines/

Como recomendación, esto es solo teoria y solo le interesa a los estándares y los browser para saber como renderizar/mostrar el html. En la vida laboral, al maquetar una web lo importante es conocer la semántica, significado y cuando utilizar de forma correcta cada uno de los elementos de HTML.